# Dispersion relations in 2 atom and above

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, dispersion

I am having a little trouble understanding this information of dispersion relations show below for a two atom basis.

[image]

So it states that there should be in total 6 dispersion branches but there only 4. I assume that this is for a 3 dimensional case as there a LA TA and TO LO.

Also what would say a 3 atom look like. Iv search wikipedia and a couple condense matter website but none really explain this graph,

Comment: Note the bit in the second bullet about there being 2 TA and 2 TO branches. For diamond cubic, the symmetry means that both branches have the same dispersion curves ($E$ vs $k$) in the [111] direction. There are 2 transverse branches because, making [111] in the $z$ direction you can distinguish $x$ vs $y$ transverse displacements.

Comment: Ok but what the case for 3 atoms ect, could you maybe expand in to an answer please.

Comment: For a general case, $n$ basis atoms in one of the 230 space groups one would generally have distinct transverse dispersion curves. The phonon $E$ vs $k$ curves for a trigonal crystal are going to be, well, ugly...